# SQL Server Compact Edition and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-2008, ssms-2005

I've been googling for hours now. I installed:

- SQL Server Compact Edition version 4.0
- SQL Server 2005 Management Studio

I could connect to SQL Server CE with 2005, but had no Data Import Wizard to get my Access 2007 DB into SQL Server CE. So - I installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

Now I can't connect to SQL Server CE :( When I connect and select 'new database' and then select a location, I get the error:

> SQL Server Compact is either not installed or the installation has
>   been corrupted. (SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider)

Any idea what the problem could be? It's very frustrating not being able to find a way to do this.  I could go back to SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and likely re-create my whole database, but would prefer to 'suck it in' for less work.

Comment: For SQL Server CE work, I prefer using [the SQL Server CE Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) by Erik EJ - it's a great VS plug-in and stand-alone tool to work with SQL Server CE.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I figured it out...

I installed SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 SP2.  Version 4.0 seems to not be supported by much of anything (3.5 SP2 is a pre-requesite).  I hadn't seen that until I installed the SQL Server Compact Toolbox and under 'Getting Started' it listed 3.5 SP2 as required and 4.0 as optional.

anyway... lesson learned and it took me a damn long time to figure that out.  I wish this SSCE stuff was better documented.

Comment: Good news are that in NeXT release coming this month, 3,5 is no longer a requirement